# Mongo Compass: Command connectionStatus not supported

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to connect to Azure Cosmos DB using Mongo Compass. I tried using connections string and filling in the fields manually.

Each time I receive the following error
"An error occurred while loading navigation: Command connectionStatus not supported."

Can someone help me resolve it?

Comment: Without sharing anything that would compromise the security of your Cosmos DB account (e.g. access key), can you please edit your question to show what, specifically, you're providing to Compass (e.g. the connection string)? Without more details, it's difficult to guess what the issue could be.

Comment: I tried using connection string provided in cosmos db and also by manually filling fields. But either way its the same.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of Azure Cosmos does not *currently* support connectionStatus.

[See Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36) for the list of supported & unsupported commands on Microsoft Azure Cosmos.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed I also have trouble connecting with Compass and the last version... As [Samantha Mellin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516145/10061561)  it appears ConnectionStatus is not supported therefore raising an error.

The turnaround I can suggest you is to use [Robot 3T](https://robomongo.org/) instead of compass. It appears that it's working with Robot 3T. However the feature in Robot 3T and Compass are slightly different, it might not be enough depending your use case.

Here is the official documentation to connect with Robot 3T : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-robomongo